# How to format date correctly

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

How do I format this date so that it is readable. I want it to show for example: "January 7th, 2018 7:30am". I tried to look at other answers but wasn't sure where to add the extension.

```
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: request.timestamp / 1000)
    dateCell.textLabel?.text = date.description



class Request {
var key:String
var sender:String
var recipient:String
var name:String
var location:String
var when:String
 var whereStr:String
var message:String
var timestamp:Double
var status:String

init(dict: [String: Any]) {
    self.key       = dict["key"] as? String ?? ""
    self.sender    = dict["sender"] as? String ?? ""
    self.recipient = dict["recipient"] as? String ?? ""
    self.name      = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.location  = dict["location"] as? String ?? ""
    self.when      = dict["when"] as? String ?? ""
    self.whereStr  = dict["where"] as? String ?? ""
    self.message   = dict["message"] as? String ?? ""
    self.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double ?? 0.0
    self.status    = dict["status"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to divide the number by 1,000?

Comment: probably because the timestamp is in _milliseconds_ not in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 func getCurrentDateTimeFromTimeStamp(timeStapm:String)->String{
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:Double(timeStapm)!/1000)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm a"
    return formatter.string(from: date as Date)
 }
```

pass timestamp and get as date in string format as per your requirement just pass dateFormat.

use like this

```
dateCell.textLabel?.text = self.getCurrentDateTimeFromTimeStamp(timeStapm:"pass your timestamp")
```

Comment: is this how I would use this? dateCell.textLabel?.text = getCurrentDateTimeFromTimeStamp(timestamp: request.timestamp)

Comment: It comes back as "June 27, 50081 23:21 PM", any way to fix this to display properly the year and time?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateFormatter:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.format = "MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm a"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Big warning, if you don't set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`, then the 12/24 hours format will be overwritten by the system locale.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extension anywhere in the app and one (same name) extension for comlpete app. look below

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerHellBoy: UIViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     dateCell.textLabel?.text = self.userFriendlyFullDate()
}




}  
extension Date: Dateable {
var  formatter: DateFormatter { return DateFormatter() }

/** Return a user friendly hour */
func userFriendlyFullDate() -> String {
    // Customize a date formatter
    formatter.dateFormat = ""MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm a"" //Use format you want to
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") . // Time zone you wishes to provide

    return formatter.string(from: self)
}
```

That is how you can use extensions. You can also create separate class and keep all extensions there.

Comment: I just don't understand how to call this on my dateCell.textLabel?.text

Answer (score 0):

Use a dateFormatter object to style the date however you want

```
let format = DateFormatter()
    format.format = "MM/dd/yyyy"

//get your date in string like this
let dateInString = format.string(from: date)

// this will give you "10/02/2018"
```

You can visit [date format examples](http://nsdateformatter.com) to see different format and how to get them.